# How do you make sure while working with mongoose that DB is queried only after we are done with connecting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

While working with native node.js mongodb drivers, one connects to DB as below:

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db'

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
  if (!err) {
    // do things with db after you are connected

    // after you are done
    db.close();
  }
});
```

In the above case, callback to `MongoClient.connect()` indicates that db is queried only after connection is established (keeping in view how things work in node). But when we connect using `mongoose.connect()`, we don't query DB in a callback, it seems that operation done on line `B` is not dependent on the success and completion of what is being attempted on line `A`, as shown below:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test'); //(A)

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', {
  name: String
});

var kitty = new Cat({
  name: 'Zildjian'
});

kitty.save(function(err) { //(B)
  if (err) // ...
    console.log('meow');
});
```

Working with native mongodb drivers feel me  more at home as far as Node's way is concerned, How does mongoose make sure the code at line `B` is executed after line `A` finished and succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.connect()` takes a callback function exactly like the native driver:

```
Mongoose.connect(uri(s), [options], [callback])
```

see here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect

Answer (score 0):

> How does mongoose make sure the code at line B is executed after line A finished and succeeded?

You may misunderstand it, it does NOT means the line A is succeeded.

Per [`mongoose.connect` source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/index.js#L292),

```
Mongoose.prototype.connect = function() {
  var conn = this.connection;
  if (rgxReplSet.test(arguments[0]) || checkReplicaSetInUri(arguments[0])) {
    return new MongooseThenable(this, conn.openSet.apply(conn, arguments));
  }

  return new MongooseThenable(this, conn.open.apply(conn, arguments));
};
```

The `MongooseThenable` is returned, and after `mongoose.connect()` is called, it call `open` to create connection, and check the connection is successful or failed through event `connected` or `error`, so it could better to save data into db in the callback of `connected` event.

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
    console.log('Could not connect to mongoDB');
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('Establish connection to mongoDB');
    kitty.save(function(err) { //(B)
      if (err) // ...
        console.log('meow');
    });
});
```